# How do I verify a route exists?

Tags: 8, routes

In Drupal 8, I need to verify a route exists or not in a custom module. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
/* @var \Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProviderInterface $route_provider */
$route_provider = \Drupal::service('router.route_provider');
$route_provider->getRouteByName('abc.xyz');
```

`RouteProviderInterface::getRouteByName()` returns a `\Symfony\Component\Routing\Route` object if it exists, or throws an exception if it does not.

You can use `RouteProviderInterface::getRoutesByNames()` if you don't want an exception.

```
$exists = count($route_provider->getRoutesByNames(['abc.xyz'])) === 1;
```

Comment: Notice that `getRoutesByNames()` can still raise an exception, if it gets an empty array as parameter. In the case of dynamically created arrays, it's better to trap the exception, or verify the array passed to the method is not empty.

Comment: Thanks aton @daniel & Kiamlaluno for helping out of this...

Comment: Thanks for the testing method!  I have added a core issue to add this as a method to RouteProvider:
https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3029545

Answer (score 6):

To check route exist or not use below function:

```
function routeExists($name)
{
    // I assume that you have a link to the container in your twig extension class
    $router = $this->container->get('router');
    return (null === $router->getRouteCollection()->get($name)) ? false : true;
}
```

Comment: Since the code is using `$this`, that is not a function, but a method of a class. You don't say which class, exactly.

Comment: Also, `(null === $router->getRouteCollection()->get($name)) ? false : true` is unnecessarily complicated. There is no need of a ternary operation, since `===` returns already a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a try catch block to catch the `RouteNotFoundException` when the route doesn't exist, or is not enabled.

```php
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException;

public function routeExists($route_to_check) {
  try {
    \Drupal::service('router.route_provider')
      ->getRouteByName($route_to_check);
  }
  catch (RouteNotFoundException $exception) {
    return NULL;
  }
}
```

This way you can call this function on a non-existent route, catch the exception, return null, or whatever, and continue the execution of the code.